# SELECT DISTINCT across multiple columns?

Tags: cockroachdb

Is it possible to select only distinct combinations of multiple columns?

E.g. only the distinct combinations of customers and the dates they placed orders (as a representation of only days they placed orders)?

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for are groups of data (which shows you only distinct combinations of values), which you can return with the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT customer_id, date
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT
 customerId, orderDate
FROM
 table;

OR

SELECT DISTINCTROW
 customerId, orderDate 
FROM
 table;